# infinite re-render of an API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch photos from an API using user-id that was fetched using another API and store the user-ids in an array. I pass each element in to API to fetch the photo and store then in a state but i get an empty array each refresh the page but then pass dependencies which gives me infinite render

this is the array of user ids

```
const [userimage,setUserimage]= React.useState<TaskImage[]>([])
const assignedid=taskdetails.map((item)=>{
        return item?.assigned_id
      })
```

```
useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData=async () => {
          try {
            const imagePromises = assignedid.map(async (element) => {
             
              const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/download/${element}`, {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accesstoken')}`
                }
                
              });
              
              const data = await response.json();
              return {
                userid: element,
                image: data.encodedBase64String
              };
            });
      
            const taskImages = await Promise.all(imagePromises);
            // Update the state with the userid and image objects
            setUserimage(taskImages);
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        };
      
        fetchData();
      }, []);
```

This function returns an empty array and if I try dependency as userimage it gives me infinite renders I tried using useCallback and useMemo but it did not solve the error how do I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should not make API call and set State call in same useEffect.
Your API call should be in some handler function which is attached to an event. And based on the response of API call you should trigger setState useEffect.

```
const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState<any>(null);
const [userimage,setUserimage]= React.useState<TaskImage[]>([])

const apiHandler = () => {
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/download/${element}`, {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accesstoken')}`
                }
               });
   const data = await response.json();
   setApiResponse(data);         
}

// For first load if needed or else you can call apiHandler from onClick of buttons
useEffect(()=>{
   apiHandler();
},[]);

useEffect(()=>{
   if(apiResponse){
      const finalData = // your manipulation
      setUserImage(finalData);
   }
},[apiResponse]);
```

You can add try catch block for your api call asper your code.